# making "string".functions() functions python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I add custom methods/attributes to built-in Python types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types)

Throughout using Python I have seen many things that can be used on strings such as `.lower()` or `.startswith()` or `.endswith()`, however, I am unsure on how to make functions that act similar to it, as what I thought of would have to use a class that passes the string to the function, and I simply want to do something like `"the string".myfunc()` instead of `MyClassObjWithString.myfunc()`.

Is there any way to make functions like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, string literals are always of type `basestring` (or `str` in py3k).  As such, you can't add methods to string literals.  You can create a class which accepts a string in the constructor and has methods which might be useful:

```
MyClass("the string").myfunc()
```

Of course, then it would probably be argued that you should be writing a function:

```
myfunc("the string")
```

Comment: So, I take it python doesn't have any 'prototype' mechanism a-la javascript that would let you overright/extend basestring (right?). But can you have MyClass derive from basicstring, so all methods available in basicstring will be available as well. e.g. MyClass("the string").lower()?

Comment: @Uri -- That is correct.

Comment: apology, my second question was NOT a yes/no question (although it was worded this way). Can you please point me HOW to inherit from basicstring.

Comment: `class MyString(basestring): pass` -- If you're just working with ascii, then `class MyString(str): pass` is probably easier.  See the link that was posted as a possible duplicate on the question as well.  There's an exmple there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a function with which you can do

```
"the string".myfunc()
```

because that would mean modifying the string class. But why not just write a method with which you could do

```
myfunc("the string")
```

Something like

```
def myfunc(s):
   return s * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

These are methods and while you can add or replace methods to (some) classes after they have been defined - a practice called monkey-patching - it is highly discouraged and not possible with builtin classes.

Just use a function.