# How to get "17"<"9" to create an error?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, comparison

Is there any good way to get rid of the possibility of application to strings of the greater smaller comparison operators and the min max functions? Like aliasing? The problem is that the behaviour is just not useful to me.

So that '17'<'9' gives an error and not the (for me) beautifully useless and confusing results it does now?
This has caused trouble for me multiple times in the form of:

```
'17'<'9'
True
```

I mean i could alias them to throw an exception if strings are used I guess but I would like a canonical way if that exsists.

**Please don't explain lexicographical ordering or int() to me...**

Comment: You mean you don't want to use comparison operators to compare strings?

Comment: I ment that i don't want string comparisons to be possible like that and to get an error instead.

Comment: No.  Instead, don't keep values in string form if you want to compare them numerically.

Comment: well that is of course better. but not the question.

Comment: That is a feature of the language and we cannot change it.

Comment: Strings have ordering, otherwise you couldn't *sort* them. It is that order that informs the `<` and `>` operators. You can't just disable them for strings, no.

Comment: Also, the results are in no way "undefined".  They're defined by the lexicographic order of the characters in the strings.

Comment: `hey` sorts before `ho` because `e` sorts before `o` in the alphabet. Strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: I know all that that was not my question was it?

Comment: Why don't you check the type first then? `isinstance(x, str)`

Comment: yes or i could do int() but thats not the question

Comment: What you want to do is either changing the interpreter or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types) and I dont think you want to redefine the string class

Answer (score 1):

I'll risk flames... :-) What you can do is create a new string class, almost identical to the native one, but with providing a new set of equality functions.

For example, just overriding the `>` operation:

```
class newstr(str):  # Inheriting str class

    def __gt__(self, s):
        raise RuntimeError("This is an error")
```

Now

```
In [1]: a = newstr('17')
In [2]: b = newstr('9')

In [3]: a<b
Out[3]: True   #since we haven't override __lt__

In [4]: a>b
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-f269bf469c37>", line 1, in <module>
    a>b

  File ".../untitled0.py", line 6, in __gt__
    raise RuntimeError("This is an error")

RuntimeError: This is an error
```

Use `__lt__` and `__eq__` for other equality conditions.