# How to write a method like islower , isupper?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class, methods

I want to write a method which i can use with strings same like we use `"word".isupper` return `False`, "word".islower return `True`, so I want to define a class and want to use like `"word".isspecial()`

so if i have a list of special characters :

```
special=["&","*",")("]
```

and I want that if I have a word I can check like  ")(".method() and it return True as we do with "string".islower() which return True

I know I can do this with simple loop and `in` operator but I want to know how I can do like `")(".method()`

What I tried is buggy:

```
class Lower:

    def check(self,x):
        for i in lower:
            if x==i:
                return True

check1=Lower()

check1.check()

print(check1.check(special,")("))
```

Comment: buggy is an understatement... what are your issues exactly?

Comment: You'll need to subclass `str`.

Comment: I can't see any reason for this having to be a method rather than a function. Is this a requirement or was it your decision?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do what you want like this:

```
import string

special_set = set(string.punctuation)

def isspecial(s):
    return all(c in special_set for c in s)

print(isspecial(")("))
print(isspecial(")(*)(&)(*&)*&"))
print(isspecial(")(*)(&)(*&)*&x"))
```

This will output, as expected:

```
True
True
False
```

Note I've used `string.punctuation` to build the set of "special characters". You can define this set by hand if you like.

Really, this is the Pythonic way to do what you want - there's no reason to have to have a method doing this. If you really insist, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types) question for more information, but beware it will become messy.