# PythonAnywhere Flask Website Template Engine problems

Tags: pythonanywhere

Here's my error log

```
2019-03-08 00:56:11,955: Error running WSGI application
2019-03-08 00:56:11,956: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lineno'
2019-03-08 00:56:11,956:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
2019-03-08 00:56:11,957:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,957: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,957:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
2019-03-08 00:56:11,957:     response = self.handle_exception(e)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,957: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,957:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1547, in handle_exception
2019-03-08 00:56:11,958:     return self.finalize_request(handler(e), from_error_handler=True)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,958: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,958:   File "/home/acehouse/mysite/flask_app.py", line 35, in internal_error
2019-03-08 00:56:11,958:     return render_template("error.html")
2019-03-08 00:56:11,958: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,958:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
2019-03-08 00:56:11,959:     return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
2019-03-08 00:56:11,959: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,959:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
2019-03-08 00:56:11,959:     return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,959: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,959:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
2019-03-08 00:56:11,960:     return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
2019-03-08 00:56:11,960: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,960:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
2019-03-08 00:56:11,960:     template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,960: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,960:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
2019-03-08 00:56:11,961:     code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,961: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,961:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 581, in compile
2019-03-08 00:56:11,961:     defer_init=defer_init)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,961: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,961:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 543, in _generate
2019-03-08 00:56:11,962:     optimized=self.optimized)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,962: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,962:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 82, in generate
2019-03-08 00:56:11,962:     generator.visit(node)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,962: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,962:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/visitor.py", line 38, in visit
2019-03-08 00:56:11,963:     return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,963: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,963:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 754, in visit_Template
2019-03-08 00:56:11,963:     self.blockvisit(node.body, frame)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,963: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,963:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 378, in blockvisit
2019-03-08 00:56:11,964:     self.visit(node, frame)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,964: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,964:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/visitor.py", line 38, in visit
2019-03-08 00:56:11,964:     return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,964: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,965:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 1297, in visit_Output
2019-03-08 00:56:11,965:     self.writeline('yield ', item)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,965: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,965:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 399, in writeline
2019-03-08 00:56:11,965:     self.newline(node, extra)
2019-03-08 00:56:11,965: 
2019-03-08 00:56:11,966:   File "/home/acehouse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 405, in newline
2019-03-08 00:56:11,966:     if node is not None and node.lineno != self._last_line:
```

It seems like the template engine for flask is having some errors. I haven't changed my code that much. I noticed that visiting any url using render_template causes this error. It might be a server side issue. Since I have git i have tried reverting some changes but that didn't work. I have tried reloading many times and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here.  I guessed your website name from the username in the stack trace, and it looks like it's working now -- did you work out what the problem was?

Comment: I was trying to add a method to list using this method([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types) but using lists and replacing __builtins__ with its python 3 equavilent. Once I removed the lines, everything was fine. BTW the pythonanywhere forum wouldn't let me post so I decided to resort to stack overflow

Comment: OK, glad you worked it out.  What error did you get when you tried to post on our forums?

Comment: I think it posted alright but it didn't show up the list of threads so I thought it didn't post