# Can you make functions that operate on a list in python?

Tags: python, list, function, class

In python you have built-in functions that operate on lists such as `list.remove()` and `list.pop()`.

Can you make your own custom functions that do this? I want to be able to do this:

```py
def removeAll(self,value):
  while value in self:
    self.remove(value)

list = ["1","2","3","3","4","3","5"]
list.removeAll("3")
print(list)
#Outputs '["1","2","4","5"]
```

Just an example.

Comment: As a general answer, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types)

Comment: You want to extend `List` class or it will be single function that takes `list` as input and new list as output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the built-in types, but you can certainly derive your own class from list:

```
class mylist(list):
    def removeAll(self,n):
        while n in self:
            self.remove(n)

x = mylist([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4])
x.removeAll(3)
print(x)
```

Comment: Ow my algorithmic complexity. A better version would do a bunch of indexing and (carefully) equal-sized slice assignments.

Comment: Well, if I were doing this for real, I'd do the inverse: create a new list that only includes the elements I want.  The algorithm was not the point; the point was "can we extend the built-in list class".

Answer (score -1):

I hope that this will help you !

```
list1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
def operations_on_a_list():
    a = input("Enter the number which you want to delete or remove : ")
    list1.remove(a)
    return list1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(operations_on_a_list())
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Sorry, for that but now I have corrected my mistake. Hope that it will help you now.

Comment: The question was about adding methods to the list type. This doesn't answer the question at all.