# Overriding "__getattr__" on lists (and other built-in types) in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

i'd like to override the `__getattr__` method of several built-in types in python. I want to accomplish the following: Each time an attribute of a default type's instance it accessed, a method `test()` should be called instead.

I've tried (e.g. for `list`):

```py
list.__getattr__ = test
```

However this gives me an exception:

```
TypeError: cannot set '__getattr__' attribute of immutable type 'list'
```

Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: inherit list to your new class and define the method there and use the new class for all purpose

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about your use case. Is this for testing? Does this have to apply to lists created with list literal syntax? Stuff like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add custom methods/attributes to built-in Python types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types)

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні No, it's just for fun. I want to implement a counter that counts how often an arbitrary object's attributes are called. This should work for all objects, i.e. Lists, Dicts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well built-in classes are... err... *built-in*. It means that they are not ordinary Python classes with a writable attribute dictionary, but have fixed attributes. The underlying rationales are:

- to avoid the chicken and egg problem support classes cannot be written in Python
- heavily used support classes are written in C language for better performances
- the internals of C classes and of Python classes do not exhibit a 1-1 relationship (still for performance reasons, and for historical reasons too...)

Because of that, the blessed way is to first *inherit* from the class you want to change and then configure the subclass to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/-zsV0_QrfTw) minute 2:51 where he explains how to inherit from an immutable class to override its `__new__` method.
I think you should inherit from `list` and define a `__getattr__` function.

As usual, make sure you want to work with [`__getattr__`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattr.html) and not [`__getattribute__`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattribute.html).