# Is it possible to overload operators for native datatypes?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, overloading

For example, if I try to do:

```
a_string + an_int
```

... where a_string is type 'str' and an_int is type 'int', or:

```
an_int + a_string
```

There would be a `TypeError` because there is no implicit conversion of the types. I understand that if I were using my own subclasses of int and string, I would be able to overload the `__add__()` method in my classes to achieve this.

However, out of curiosity, I would like to know: would it be possible to overload the + operator in the class definitions of `int` and `str`, so that `__add__(int,str)` and `__add__(str,int)` automatically concatenate them as strings?

If not, what are the reasons why a programmer should not overload the operators for a native datatype?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's a good explanation of how to overload operators in a user-defined class.. however, I'm wondering if it's possible to do it for native datatypes such as 'str' and 'int'.

Comment: Is it for python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.2 on my machine at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, without reverting to the C-level API, you cannot modify attributes of builtin types (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444680/how-do-i-add-my-own-custom-attributes-to-existing-built-in-python-types-like-a)). You can, however, subclass builtin types and do what you want on the new types. For the question you specifically asked (making the addition string based), you'd modify [`__add__` and `__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

```
class Int(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Int(int(str(self) + str(other)))

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Int(str(other) + str(self))

>>> Int(5) + 3
53

>>> 3 + Int(5) + 87
3587
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any Pythonic reason why we are not allowed to change member attributes of built-in types?

Comment: It might cause stuff that's too weird: your program would malfunction, and you couldn't figure out why, because string's `__str__` form could mean one crazy thing, and the the debugger wouldn't work because integer addition would mean some other crazy thing.

Comment: Is there any way to apply this wrapper for all current/future operators...? it's not trivial to just loop over all attributes--you don't want to wrap the return value of i.e. `__new__` or the inequalities. (Not sure about truediv return value)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out above, you can't (unless you are up to building your own Python implementation). That is, you cannot change the way `'1'+1` is handled if encountered in code. But you can mess with builtin *functions* however you please:

```
>>> int = str
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> type('1')
<class 'str'>
>>> int(1)
'1'
>>> type(int(1))
<class 'str'>
```

It's little more than an enlightening example of first-class functions' awesomeness, thoug. Any changes you make stay in a namespace you are making them in. Consider this:

```
>>> str=int
>>> str('1')
1
>>> str('asd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asd'
>>> input()
2
'2'
>>>
```

You are using whatever you put in `str`, in this case `int`. But `input()` knows better and falls back to the builtins. There may be some weird trick with closures that'll make it refer to your implementation, but I can't find it. By the way, original `str` is in `__builtins__.str`, should you need it back.

Pulling the same trick on builtin's methods doesn't work:

```
>>> int.__add__ = str.__add__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

Comment: I don't think `int = str` is messing with built-ins. `int` and `str` are both existing variables, but setting `int = ...` in module scope will instead create a new global variable that *shadows* the existing built-ins.