# Turn `1+1==3` to return True on Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Strange question: I want this expression to be True.
`1+1==3`, although I know it’s not :).

```
if 1+1==3: 
    print("This is True...")
```

I know I can do it by creating a class (let’s say `a`) and overloading its `__add__` function, but it requires me to write `a(1)+a(1)==3`.

Can I do it without writing an additional code (sure I can write code before and after, but the line above will be as is)?

Comment: You could maybe register a new source codec that wraps literals in a custom class that has the necessary overrides. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203589/possible-to-make-custom-string-literal-prefixes-in-python) has some pointers for writing custom source codecs.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38832002/11199298). It looks like you can't do that on "normal" Python

Comment: @ddulaney great idea I’ll check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it according to @ddulaney suggestion: create my own codec `my_true` and write my own `decode` function.

I have 3 files:

1. **register.py**:

```
import codecs, io, encodings
from encodings import utf_8

def my_true_decode(input, errors="strict"):
    raw = bytes(input).decode("utf-8")
    code = raw.replace('1+1==3','1+1==2')
    return code, len(input)

def search_function(encoding):
    if encoding != "my_true":
        return None
    utf8 = encodings.search_function("utf8")
    return codecs.CodecInfo(
        name="my_true",
        encode=utf8.encode,
        decode=my_true_decode,
    )

codecs.register(search_function)
```

2. **script.py**:

```
# coding: my_true
if 1+1==3: 
    print("This is True...")
```

3. **run.py**:

```
import register
import script
```

Now run `python3 run.py`

Output is `This is True...`