# How to create a wordcloud with the same word several times but with different colors?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I need a wordcloud in which the same word could appear twice with different colors; red indicating negative associations, and green positive.

I am already able to generate a wordcloud with repeated words using MultiDicts (see the code below):

[image]

However, I need one of the homes to appear in green color. Is this possible with the wordcloud libray? Can somebody recommend another library that support this?

---

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from multidict import MultiDict

class WordClouder(object):

    def __init__(self, words, colors):
        self.words = words
        self.colors = colors

    def get_color_func(self, word, **args):
        return self.colors[word]

    def makeImage(self, path):
        wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", width=200, height=100)

        # generate word cloud
        wc.generate_from_frequencies(self.words)

        # color the wordclound
        wc.recolor(color_func=self.get_color_func)

        image = wc.to_image()
        image.save(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Ideally this would be used somewhere
    colors_valence = {
        '+': 'green',
        '-': 'red',
    }

    colors = {
        'home': 'red',
        'car': 'green',
    }

    words = MultiDict({
        'home': 2.0, # This home should be green
        'car': 20.0,
    })

    words.add('home',10) , # This home should be red


    wc = WordClouder(words, colors)
    wc.makeImage('wordcloud.png')
```

Comment: Do you understand the code that you wrote? `def get_color_func` returns a color based on *the exact word*. So either make a dummy word `home ` and give that another color, or rewrite the entire word <-> color system to something else.

Comment: Do you mean add a blank space to home so I have `"home "` and `"home"`? I thought about that, but in reality I will have more than two categories (positive and negative is just a simplified example to make the question easy to understand). If I have 5 categories, there will be 4 white spaces, and then the word clouds start to look weird. In any case, it would not be a very elegant solution, more like a hack.

Comment: Then, as I said, you need to add another way of distinguishing the variants. As it is now, the color is inextricably linked to the word.

Comment: Well, yes, that is my question. If the wordcloud library supports this, or if somebody can recommend an alternative. I looked into the wordcloud code, and this doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: I thought of adding atributes to strings, but it is [not very recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444680/how-do-i-add-my-own-custom-attributes-to-existing-built-in-python-types-like-a), another monkey patch.

Answer (score 2):

I created a decent solution by inherit from WordCloud. You can just copy and paste the code below, and then you can use + and - to indicate the color, something like this:

```
words = {
    'home+': 2.0,
    'home-': 10.0,
    'car+': 5.0,
}
```

would generate this:

[image]

---

---

**Explanation**: I added a character after the word in the dictionary that tells me the color (`+` or `-`). I removed the character in the `recolor` method of the `WordCloud` that I overwrote, but I did send the entire world (including the character + or -) to the `color_fun` that I use to select the appropriate color. I commented the important bits in the code below.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud as WC

from multidict import MultiDict


class WordCloud(WC):

    def recolor(self, random_state=None, color_func=None, colormap=None):
        if isinstance(random_state, int):
            random_state = Random(random_state)
        self._check_generated()

        if color_func is None:
            if colormap is None:
                color_func = self.color_func
            else:
                color_func = colormap_color_func(colormap)

        # Here I remove the character so it doesn't get displayed
        # when the wordcloud image is produced
        self.layout_ = [((word_freq[0][:-1], word_freq[1]), font_size, position, orientation,
               # but I send the full word to the color_func
               color_func(word=word_freq[0], font_size=font_size,
                          position=position, orientation=orientation,
                          random_state=random_state,
               font_path=self.font_path))
               for word_freq, font_size, position, orientation, _
                   in self.layout_]

        return self


class WordClouder(object):

    def __init__(self, words, colors):
        self.words = words
        self.colors = colors

    def get_color_func(self, word, **args):
        return self.colors[word[-1]]

    def makeImage(self, path):
        #alice_mask = np.array(Image.open("alice_mask.png"))

        wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", width=200, height=100)

        # generate word cloud
        wc.generate_from_frequencies(self.words)

        # color the wordclound
        wc.recolor(color_func=self.get_color_func)

        image = wc.to_image()
        image.save(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    colors = {
        '+': '#00ff00',
        '-': '#ff0000',
    }

    words = {
        'home+': 2.0,
        'home-': 10.0,
        'car+': 5.,
    }

    wc = WordClouder(words, colors)
    wc.makeImage('wc.png')
```